# Characteristic function evaluated at complex number for exponential distributed random variable

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions, exponential-distribution

Given:

$$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x},\; x\in X$$

Wanted: The corresponding characteristic function  $\phi(ju)$.

\begin{align}
\phi(ju)&=\mathbb{E}(e^{j^2ux})\\
&= \lambda \int^{\infty}_0 e^{-ux}e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
&= \lambda \int^{\infty}_0 e^{(-u-\lambda) x}dx \\
&= \lambda \left [ \frac{1}{-u-\lambda} e^{-u-\lambda)x}  \right]^{\infty}_0\\
&= \lambda \left [ 0 - \frac{1}{-u-\lambda} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda - u } 
\end{align}

The definition of the characteristic function is

$$ \phi(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{jtx})~. $$

Can I set $t$ equal to $ju$? So so that the definition is

$$ \phi(t=ju) = \mathbb{E}(e^{jjux})~?$$

Comment: The characteristic function is defined over the reals only. This is stated within the first couple of lines of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), or any textbooks that deals with characteristic functions. It makes no sense to talk about $\phi(t=ju)$, unless one has some really great ideas expanding the measure-theoretic treatment of probability. One can always make the calculation, but it doesn't correspond to anything in probability.